# Issue passing comma delimited value to SelectCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code in my .cs file:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["LocID"].DefaultValue = "5957,5958";
```

I have the following code in my .aspx file

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:KuzSQL %>" OnSelecting="DataSourceSelecting"
    SelectCommand="Select ID, RoomNum from [dbo].[Mbiology] WHERE LocId IN (@LocId)" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="LocId" />
    </SelectParameters>        
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '5957,5958' to data type int.

Note that LocId is of type Int.

Comment: That's not how parameters and `IN` work.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are not just "inserted" into the SQL like you seem to think they are.  It is tricky to try and pass a list of values into a query and use them in an `IN` clause.

Some options:

1. Pass the values as a string into a stored procedure that parses the string into a temp table, then use `IN`
2. Setup your command with several parameters (`LocId1`, `LocId2`, etc.) and change your query to:

   ```
   Select ID, RoomNum from [dbo].[Mbiology] 
   WHERE LocId IN (@LocId1, @LocId2, @LocId3, @LocId4, @LocId5, @LocId6, ...)
   ```
3. Save your paramteres to a different table (maybe with a `"sessionID"` key) and pull from that in your `IN` clause.
4. Don't support multiple values in one query.

Comment: Or just use table valued parameters which SQL Server has supported for years.

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlDataSource` control does not support this type of operation, instead you have, at least, the following options:

1. Build the query in code-behind.

   ```
   protected void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Create list of strings to hold ID values
       List<string> locIDs = new List<string>();

       // Build list of actual string values
       foreach (var item in SomeControl.Items)
       {
           locIDs.Add(value);
       }

       // Build SELECT command
       SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = String.Format("Select ID, RoomNum from [dbo].[Mbiology] WHERE LocId IN ({0})", 
           String.Join(", ", productIDs.ToArray()));
   }
   ```
2. Create a stored procedure and pass the list of ID values as a parameter.

Comment: Hi Karl, can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775586/selectparameters and let me know where I am going wrong. - Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure and create your sql query dynamically inside it. your procedure would be something like this -

```
create procedure p1_proc
    @val varchar(250)
as
begin
    declare @sql as varchar(500)
    set @sql = 'Select ID, RoomNum from [dbo].[Mbiology] WHERE LocId IN ('+@val+')'
    exec(@sql)
end
```

so your `sqldatasource` will call this procedure. something like this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:KuzSQL %>" OnSelecting="DataSourceSelecting"
    SelectCommand="p1_proc" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="val" />
    </SelectParameters>        
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and you can pass the `LocId`s as a comma separated string.

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["val"].DefaultValue = "5957,5958";
```

Comment: Hello,Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775586/selectparameters and let me know where I am going wrong. Have it similar to the way you mentioned above.